# Multiple markers with infobox

Tags: google-maps-markers, infobox

I have multiple markers on my map. The infobox opens for each marker on mouseover.
When I hover over an infobox covering some markers, the mouseover eventof those underlying markers get called.
Have tried setting optimized property of marker to false. But after doing that the infobox opens only for the first time. Never opens up after hovering over marker once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
I figured it out.  I had to add a listener for the infoWindow's domready event and call my jPages from within there.  Working perfectly now.

```
                    // Add event listener for the infoWindow 
                google.maps.event.addListener(cbMapInfoWindow, 'domready', function() {
                    $('#cboxLoadedContent iframe').contents().find('.infoWindowHolder').jPages({
                        containerID : "infoWindowContainer"
                    });
                });
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/GuB92/3/